# Cannot render nested data returned by UseTracker in Meteor - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-hooks

I have a functional component that gets data using UseTracker(). The data returned is a single 'Wine' object and an array of related 'Recipe' objects (the join is done in the publication).  Both object types have nested arrays and objects within them:

```
export default function Wine(props){

    const { _id } = useParams();

    const { wine, recipes, isLoading  } = useTracker(() => {
        const documentId = _id;
        const noData = { wine: {}, recipes: [] };
        const handler = Meteor.subscribe(Wines.singlePublicationName, documentId);
        if(!handler.ready()){
            return { ...noData, isLoading: true}
        }
        const wine = Wines.collection.findOne(documentId);
        const recipes = Recipes.collection.find().fetch();
        return { 
            wine, 
            recipes,
            isLoading: !handler.ready() 
        }

        });

    return(
        <div>
           {isLoading ? 'loading' : 
             <div>
               <h1>{wine.name}</h1>
               <p>{wine.type}</p>
               <p>{wine.orign.region}</p>
             </div> }
        </div>
    );
}
```

The JSON for the Wine object is:

```
{ 
      "name": "Yummy Cuisine - Chardonnay",
      "type": "White",
      "subtype": "Chardonnay",
      "origin": {
        "country": "USA",
        "region": "California"
}
```

I am getting the following console error: 'Cannot read property 'region' of undefined'. I cannot find any information regarding this type of problem using UseTracker specifically; I would think that the subscription handler would take care of fully resolving the data before returning ready(), so that nested data could be rendered.

I am new to Meteor and React and would appreciate any advice :)

Comment: typo `wine.orign` -> `wine.origin`?

Comment: @ChristianFritz thank you! *facepalm*